# How to merge old azure webjob functions together in dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

During development of my webjob i have redeployed it multiple times to Azure. When i visit the webjob dashboard i am greeted by this:

[image: redeployed-webjob overview]

It seems that every webjob deployment gets registered as a new function, deprecating the old one. Searching around how to alter this behaviour (fold all previous functions together with the current one) gives no results.

Does anybody know how to configure the azure webjob dashboard to merge previous functions together if name+arguments are still the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function list/index for a job host exe is based on the fully qualified assembly name. One thing I can think of that might cause the above would be if your assembly name is changing each time you deploy for some reason. Do you have anything like that going on?

Another question: do you have multiple job hosts sharing the same dashboard storage account?

Comment: Hmmm if it is based on the fully qualified assembly name that would make sense. I am updating the application version with each deployment.  There are no other job hosts sharing the same dashboard.

Comment: Ok then that explains it. This is the expected behavior, since each unique host (i.e. assembly hosting jobs) is tracked and indexed separately. I recommend that you use a stable assembly name if you plan on using the dashboard. To clean up the old entries, you could delete the Dashboard storage tables in your storage account to "start fresh".